# Limit Windows10 update to security updates only

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I found a rather [old article from 2016](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-recieve-security-updates-only/58ef6035-607c-498c-b026-d1db63e3d327) which allows you to limit your Windows 10 updates to security updates only. With the current version 21H2 this option is not available any more (not for Win10 Pro). I search around a little be on the web but except for going for [2nd week Tuesday patches](https://superuser.com/questions/1412616/windows-10-how-can-i-install-only-patch-tuesday-updates-not-c-and-d-update) I didn't find any solution. Is the option gone for good or is it still accessible?

Note: found another question [(Why do I need to download a 'new' version of Windows 10?)](https://superuser.com/questions/1633279/why-do-i-need-to-download-a-new-version-of-windows-10), but this didn't give me any usable info either.

Comment: You can use this software to control (chose) Windows updates, works for W11 also>>>>https://superuser.com/questions/947706/make-windows-10-stop-installing-driver-software-automatically/983535#983535

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/questions/1412616/windows-10-how-can-i-install-only-patch-tuesday-updates-not-c-and-d-update) answer hasn't been applicable to a supported version of Windows 10 for almost 2.5 years now.

Comment: @Ramhound are you sure? Tuesday patches are still referenced by the MS website [here (old)](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-it-pro-blog/windows-10-update-servicing-cadence/ba-p/222376) or rather [here (new)](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-it-pro-blog/windows-quality-updates-primer/ba-p/2569385)

Comment: @Albin - Am I positive that my own answer is outdated. Yes; It is. However, I don’t feel it’s necessary to update an answer to a question about a 3 year old version of Windows 10. Especially when it’s not applicable. What you can pause and prevent is entirely dependent on the version of Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I search around a little be on the web but except for going for 2nd
> week Tuesday patches I didn't find any solution. Is the option gone
> for good or is it still accessible?

If you go into Windows 10 Updates, Advanced Options and look at that list, all that is available in the newest Windows 10 versions is to Pause Updates.

You can pause for about 30 days, at which point updates will happen any way.  Pretty much the same for Windows 11 as well (done via Update Policy settings).

In either case, you cannot do just Security updates and not Feature upgrades.

You can look at Long Term Service versions to help you for a period of time, but not indefinitely.

Also if in a Corporate environment with WSUS, you can have more management capabilities. But even Corporations will update at some point (more frequently than annually). Some security updates get mashed into Cumulative updates. I have seen this before.

Some people - I have seen it at customers and I have seen it here - shoot themselves in the foot by not updating.

After 6 years with Windows 10 and nearly a year with Windows 11, I do not recommend failing to update. That causes more problems than it solves.

Comment: Thanks, of course I know about the pause function, but that's not really my question. Or maybe I misunderstood you?

Comment: That is all you can do for Update settings in the newest Windows 10 systems.  You cannot do just Security Updates.  Feature updates will now happen.

Comment: so essentially the conclusion from my question is correct, you only can go by the update weeks, to have at least a little bit of control? OK, I guess you could still go for some kind of manual update (if it's worth the time).

Comment: When updates come along, you can pause them. Companies can use WSUS. Individuals (most of us) cannot avoid updating. I see the same thing in Windows 11 as well.

Comment: Updating can be avoided indefinitely as long as you use at least the Pro version. WSUS might be a available work around, I will look into that, thanks.

Comment: In a consumer (individual) environment , updates cannot be put off indefinitely any more. WSUS is more a planning tool, not an an indefinite put off. You can look into Long Term Service version that will provide Security only updates but eventually Long Term Service versions must be upgraded to stay viable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134153/discussion-between-albin-and-john).

Comment: You can absolutely block feature updates on Windows 10 and Windows 11.  It requires you to simply set a group policy.  However, the only updates for Windows 10, actually are labeled as security updates.  Articles from 2016, with regards to Windows Updates, are not applicable to Windows 10 or Windows 11.  Far to much as changed in 6 years.  **It is pointless to block future feature updates on Windows 10 since Windows 10 21H1 at this time is the last planned feature update.**  I have also submitted answers on this subject in the past that specified which group policy it is.

Comment: Support for a specific feature update can still expire, that means security updates will not be released, if you are using Home or Professional.  Only the LTSC editions can remain on their respective feature update. Microsoft discontinued the concept of Windows Quality and Security updates.  All updates are just cumulative updates.  The week of the month, determines, if they are an B, C, or D update.

Comment: There is a Cumulative Windows 10 update along with some Intel updates happening right now. Most users who try to stop update usually just shoot themselves in the foot.

Comment: Optional updates are just that, optional, and are NOT automatically installed.  Only Windows Defender, .NET, and Cumulative updates are automatically patched.  Basically by default security updates are installed, anything that isn't a security update, is already optional so the user must seek the update in order to install it.

Comment: Cumulative Updates can still be paused as desired and may include updates to older updates considered back then (whenever) to be security updates.