# How to enable security updates only on windows 11 pro?

Tags: windows, windows-11

Is it possible to enable security updates only on windows 11 pro? Is there any workaround to delay feature updates?

Comment: [same question for Win10](https://superuser.com/questions/1705100/limit-windows10-update-to-security-updates-only)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some feature updates (Windows 11 and 10) include security updates alongside, so the general answer to your question is no.

You can, however, use the settings in Windows Updates to delay updates for a number of days until it is convenient for you to do the updates.

Microsoft is less and less (from my perspective) separating updates into just security and other.

The other thing you can try to do is investigate Windows 11 LTSC when it comes available.

https://www.minitool.com/news/windows-11-ltsc.html